# Using Euler for estimating $\pi$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pi

From Euler we know that  $\pi ^{2} / 6 = \sum 1/ n^{2}$. Is this a good approximation for estimating $\pi$ ?

Comment: It is one of the many many ways to approximate $\pi$. Are you looking for faster convergent series ?

Comment: Yes. But why is the convergent time slow with Euler?

Comment: If you define $a_n=\frac 1{n^2}$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n^2}{(1+n)^2}$ which is quite slowly decreasing.

Comment: What do you mean by good approximation?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html could be of interest to you.

Comment: See [list of formulae involving $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_pi).